# Admob ad using XML in android, Ads are shown properly on emulator but not on real device

Tags: android, admob

I have added these lines to proguard-project.txt

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {
    public *;
}

-keep public class com.google.ads.** {
    public *;
}
```

and  Xml Code for Ads

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="I have filled my app id here"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

Java Code for loading

```
// Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

the thing is ads are running properly on emulator with warning in logcat that google play service is missing so its using test device id by itself and displays add. when i run this app on my physical device its not showing adds. Please let me know where i mistaken and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run on your device it will always generate log whenever an ad request is made and will log the result of that request. Look there to find out what is occurring. It is probably as simple as no ad fill being available but the log will test all.

Comment: you are right. the logcat listed the error "not enough space to display ad" i didnt know why it behaved in that way when i give the dimension of 350dp as width and 50dp as height; it worked.